# Vue Copy Paste feature, Vue list rendering

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

When I type some text into the input field and then hit enter it adding into the list with a button with the title "Copy"
Now I want when I click on the next to input it copies that input.

But its only copy the element with an index of 1

you can run this code

Please check this and let me know What is the issue

Thank you

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
      myInput: '',
      items: []
  },
  methods: {
    AddNew() {
      this.items.push(this.myInput)
      this.myInput= ""
    },
    copyText(index) {
      console.log('1 =',this.items[index])
      var textToCopy = document.querySelector(`.obj${this.items.indexOf(index)}`)
      console.log( '2 =', textToCopy);
      textToCopy.select()
      document.execCommand("copy");
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
  <div id="app">
    <input type="text" v-on:keyup.enter="AddNew" v-model="myInput">
    <div v-for="(item, index) in items" :key="index">
      <input :class="['obj-' + index]" :value="item"> {{index}}
      <button v-on:click=" copyText(index)">copy</button>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You modify an array so it's not reliable to use an index as a key and to find an item to copy.

At least pass the item itself to copyText method:

```
<div v-for="(item, index) in items" :key="index">
      <input :class="['obj-' + index]" :value="item"> {{index}}
      <button v-on:click="copyText(item)">copy</button>
</div>
...
copyText(item) {
      console.log('1 =',item)
      var textToCopy = document.querySelector(`.obj${item}`)
      console.log( '2 =', textToCopy);
      textToCopy.select()
      document.execCommand("copy");
    }
```

Comment: Thank you very much for helping me.

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple of errors where you select the element:

`` var textToCopy = document.querySelector(`.obj${this.items.indexOf(index)}`) ``

Should be this:

`` var textToCopy = document.querySelector(`.obj-${index}`) ``

You're missing a hyphen after `obj` and, as you're already passing the index, there's no need to use `indexOf`.

---

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
      myInput: '',
      items: []
  },
  methods: {
    AddNew() {
      this.items.push(this.myInput);
      this.myInput = "";
    },
    copyText(index) {
      console.log('1 =',this.items[index])
      var textToCopy = document.querySelector(`.obj-${index}`)
      console.log( '2 =', textToCopy);
      textToCopy.select()
      document.execCommand("copy");
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
  <div id="app">
    <input type="text" v-on:keyup.enter="AddNew" v-model="myInput">
    <div v-for="(item, index) in items" :key="index">
      <input :class="['obj-' + index]" :value="item"> {{index}}
      <button v-on:click="copyText(index)">copy</button>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: thank you very much brother for helping me. love you.../